# How can I prevent #1 from repeating until the next start time after #2 is finished?

Tags: python

```
while True:
    try:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        start_time = get_start_time("KRW-BTC")
        end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
```

**#1**

```
        if start_time < now < end_time - datetime.timedelta(seconds=3):
            target_price = get_target_price("KRW-BTC", 0.001)
            current_price = get_current_price("KRW-BTC")
            if target_price < current_price:
                krw = get_balance("KRW")
                if krw > 5000:
                    upbit.buy_market_order("KRW-BTC", krw*0.9995)
```

**#2**

```
        current_btc = get_balance("BTC")
        my_pocket_btc_limit = 0.0008
        if current_btc > my_pocket_btc_limit:


            avg_btc_price = upbit.get_avg_buy_price(ticker='BTC')
            r = 0.0003

            sell_price = avg_btc_price * (1 + r)

            current_price = get_current_price("KRW-BTC")
            if current_price >= sell_price: 
                sell_percent = 1 
                upbit.sell_market_order("KRW-BTC", current_btc*sell_percent)
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(1)
```

#1 is executed, and as soon as #2 is executed, #1 starts immediately. When #2 is executed, I want #1 to restart when the next start_time is reached, not the current start_time.

```
def get_start_time(ticker):
    """This is the start time lookup"""
    df = pyupbit.get_ohlcv(ticker, interval="minute5", count=1)
    start_time = df.index[0]
    return start_time
```

Can I try break, continue, for i range, etc.?

Comment: I am assuming #2 is included right after #1. First I would not include the start and end time in the loop, do not need to recalc it every time.
Is your question that you want step 1 to wait until a new tick is reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you can try this

```
while True:
    try:
        start_time = get_start_time("KRW-BTC")
        end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
        while not start_time < datetime.datetime.now() < end_time:
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        target_price = get_target_price("KRW-BTC", 0.001)
        current_price = get_current_price("KRW-BTC")
        if target_price < current_price:
            krw = get_balance("KRW")
            if krw > 5000:
                upbit.buy_market_order("KRW-BTC", krw*0.9995)
        current_btc = get_balance("BTC")
        my_pocket_btc_limit = 0.0008
        if current_btc > my_pocket_btc_limit:


            avg_btc_price = upbit.get_avg_buy_price(ticker='BTC')
            r = 0.0003

            sell_price = avg_btc_price * (1 + r)

            current_price = get_current_price("KRW-BTC")
            if current_price >= sell_price: 
                sell_percent = 1 
                upbit.sell_market_order("KRW-BTC", current_btc*sell_percent)
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(1)
```